# Data binding support in O/RM tools, how to detect

Tags: data-binding, binding, wcf-binding

I want to verify that a generated class (single entity or collection) from an O/RM tool is data binding compatible.

I read that supported data binding types in WCF are: one time, one way, two way, one way from source in WCF. But how about "old school" .NET 1.1 data binding ?

It looks kind of difficult to check in code what kind of data binding support there is. You also have difference in runtime and design time data binding support. When reading some webpages I read different kind of implementations: implement IList, IComponent, INotifyPropertyChanged, IBindingList.... pffffff I don't know exactly where to look for...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can databind to virtually any class. Let's imagine you create a very simple class, with a few properties, say for instance, Person with a Name and Age. I am talking about a plain simple class with absolutely nothing fancy about it.

If you create an instance of Person, you can do several things with it, and I will assume you are working with Windows Forms, but this mostly applies to other frameworks:
- You can bind its properties to properties of controls.
- You can bind it to datagrids, lists, etc. In the former case you can set mappings of which properties bind to which columns. In the latter, which property is displayed in the list, which property is the value selected by the user.
- Even better, you can bind it to a bindingSource.

Binding a single instance to a grid or a list isn't that useful, so what usually is done is that you create a list of instances and bind those to the grid. Even more correct is to bind the list to a bindingsource and the grid to the bindingsource also.

You can see a good article [here](http://www.15seconds.com/issue/040614.htm) about how to do all this.

Now, about all the interfaces you mention, they all only add more value to the databinding experience. Let's talk about a few of them.

- INotifyPropertyChanged. Person is not less "databindable" than any other object if it does not implement this interface. What instances of Person are not able to do, however, is notify the controls their properties are bound to that the latter have changed. Try this: Bind the Name property of a Person instance to the Text property of a TextBox. Create a button that when clicked changes the value of that instance's Name. You will see the TextBox does not update after clicking the button. If, on the other hand, you implement INotifyPropertyChanged and have the setter of the Name property raise the PropertyChangedEvent that is defined by the interface, after repeating the experience, you will see that the textbox is updated automatically.
- IEnumerable. If instead of a single Person, you want to databind not to a set of people, you can create a list of people and databind to that list. Let's take for instance, List lst = new List(); How do the databinding controls like datagrid, bindingSource, etc., know you want to bind to a set of Person(s) and not to the properties of lst itself? It is because List implements IEnumerable. So, whenever you bind these controls to an instance of anything that implements IEnumerable, the controls know that you intend to bind not to the properties of the list, but to the instances the list refers to. How do they know the type of objects the list contains? To be more generic and support any type of IEnumerable implementation, they just check the type of the first element in the list and assume all others are equal.
- IBindingList: Even if Person implements IPropertyChanged, if you group instances of Person into a List bind that list to a control and, by code, change the value of a property of one of the instances, you will see nothing happen in the screen. This happens because Person is notifying, not the binding source, but the list. But the list wasn't made for databinding, so it is not listening, nor propagating the event to the control. Lists that implement IBindingList, like BindingList, offer a better databinding support precisely by listening to the PropertyChangedEvent events of their contents and propagating them up to the databound control.

I am affraid I have given you no way of determining if an object is databoundable, because virtually all them are, but I hope I've given you a way of determining different levels of databinding support (INotifyPropertyChanged and IBindingList). I am assuming you know how to check for these via reflection.

Answer (score 1):

Any instance of a class with properties is data bindable. (in fact instances of *any* class with fields or properties at all are data bindable)

Using reflection in .NET makes it very easy to discover/use data in an object. (at a small performance cost)

**In order to answer this question** you'd need to provide the specific usage scenarios you'll be encountering.

Rui gives some good explanation of different *common* data binding patterns, but each of them is for solving specific problems.

The *right* answer is always dependent on the context.

:)